# Cannot figure out this .HTACCESS rewriterule issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have .HTACCESS file with several rewrite rules in place to give SEO-friendly URLs. For some reason, two are not working as expected. I have verified across several browsers, thinking that perhaps one browser was remembering the server response from before the .HTACCESS changes.

Here is the entire contents of my file:

```
Options +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sign-up/?$ signup.php
RewriteRule ^features/?$ features.php
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php
RewriteRule ^how-it-works/?$ how-it-works.php
RewriteRule ^client-pricing/?$ pricing.php

RewriteRule ^login/?$ admin.php
```

Two of the single-word URLs (`/about/`, and `/contact/`) result in 404 errors. All other URLs work. Strangely, another single-word URL (`/login/`) *is* working.

I have verified that the PHP files do exist on the server. I can access www.domain.com/about.php and it loads fine. But www.domain.com/about/ and www.domain.com/about both return 404.

I'm stumped... appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on rewrite logging to see what mod_rewrite is doing. But you have to do this in your server/vhost config, not in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 5
```

There's nothing wrong with your rules but those two rules are the only ones where the request (e.g. `/contact`) matches exactly the php file sans the extension. So that makes it seem like it's related to multiviews:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- it was a conflict with the rewrite matching exactly the filename.